# Selecting a date and then select the previous date before that date

Tags: sql, date-sorting

I have a table that lists items available for sale and for each one of them the date the item sold, the date the item was listed for sale and the date the item was re-advertised as for sale.

I want to get just one row for every item with the sale date, the date the item first listed before it was sold and date the advertisement was published last.

So, for the data shown below I want to get only the last row

```
Item ID Sale_Date   Listing_Date    Published_date
1466748 4/04/2012   5/12/2011 0:00  5/12/2011 0:00
1466748 4/04/2012   5/12/2011 0:00  24/12/2011 0:00
1466748 4/04/2012   5/12/2011 0:00  7/01/2012 0:00
1466748 4/04/2012   5/12/2011 0:00  4/02/2012 0:00
1466748 4/04/2012   5/12/2011 0:00  18/02/2012 0:00
1466748 4/04/2012   5/12/2011 0:00  3/03/2012 0:00
1466748 4/04/2012   5/12/2011 0:00  17/03/2012 0:00
```

Answer (score 0):

Should be as simple as something like this:

```
select item_id, min(sale_date), min(listing_date), max(published_date)
from listing_table group by item_id
```

Comment: Thanks for both replies. The query is actually a bit more complex and apologies for not having explained it too well. Because an item can be sold and re-listed more than once in the specified period I'm actually after some logic that allows me to retrieve the first listing and published date on or before the sale date. I'm adding a different example data set. hope it clarifies !

Comment: ITEM ID SOLD DATE LISTING DATE PUBLISHED DATE
5609050 24/07/2003 22/07/2003 22/07/2003
5609050 5/04/2007 31/03/2007 31/03/2007
5609050 5/04/2007 31/03/2007 14/04/2007
5609050 5/04/2007 31/03/2007 21/04/2007
5609050 5/04/2007 31/03/2007 24/04/2007
5609050 5/04/2007 31/03/2007 5/05/2007
5609050 5/04/2007 31/03/2007 19/05/2007
5609050 24/05/2012 15/05/2012 15/05/2012
5609050 24/05/2012 15/05/2012 17/05/2012
5609050 24/05/2012 15/05/2012 24/05/2012

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the Sale Date and Listing Date will be the same for all rows for a given Item ID,

```
SELECT ITEM_ID, SALE_DATE, LISTING_DATE, MAX( PUBLISHED_DATE)
FROM YOUR_TABLE
GROUP BY ITEM_ID, SALE_DATE, LISTING_DATE;
```